# validation and rich: popupPanel don't work

Tags: jsf, richfaces, popuppanel

My intention is to display a message to the user in a rich: popupPanel after insert a record in BD.

With the code below I get to do what I want, but with a problem. Only works when I type all page fields correctly. If one of the fields does not pass in validation, the validation message is displayed in the h:messages, and the page does not change, even if I change the contents of the field and click the button again.

What could be wrong?

- page

  ```
  <h:outputLabel value="Nome:" for="nome1" />
  <h:inputText id="nome1" maxlength="50" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe um nome" immediate="true"/>

  <h:outputLabel value="Logradouro:" for="logradouro" />
  <h:inputText id="logradouro" maxlength="50" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe o logradouro" immediate="true"/>

  <h:outputLabel value="Bairro:" for="bairro" />
  <h:inputText id="bairro" maxlength="45" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe o bairro" immediate="true" />

  <h:outputLabel value="CEP:" for="cep" />
  <h:inputText id="cep" maxlength="8" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe o CEP" immediate="true">
      <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" groupingUsed="false" maxIntegerDigits="8" />
  </h:inputText>

  <a4j:commandButton id="btnInserirDizimista" value="Inserir" oncomplete="#{rich:component('pnlOk')}.show()" render="pnlMessages outPnlOk" actionListener="#{dizimistaMB.inserirDizimista}"/>

  <a4j:outputPanel id="outPnlOk" ajaxRendered="true">
  <rich:popupPanel id="pnlOk" modal="true" height="150">
          <h:graphicImage value="/images/info.jpg" />
          <h:outputText id="textoModalOk" value="#{dizimistaMB.textoModal}" />
          <h:commandButton value="OK" action="dizimista?faces-redirect=true"
              onclick="#{rich:component('pnlOk')}.hide(); return false;" >
              <a4j:ajax execute="formPnlOk" />
          </h:commandButton>
      </rich:popupPanel>
  </a4j:outputPanel>
  ```
- managed bean

  ```
  public void inserirDizimista(){
      try{
          defineDizimista("formNovoDizimista");
          dizimistaFacade.criar(dizimista);
          setTextoModal("Dizimista inserido com sucesso");
          System.out.println("Dizimista '" + dizimista.getNome1() + "' inserido com sucesso");
          dizimista = null;
      } catch (DAOException e) {
          FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), null);
          JSFHelper.getFacesContext().addMessage("ATENÇÃO!", msg);
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  private void defineDizimista(String nomeForm){
      Map<String, String> dados = getDadosFormulario(nomeForm);
      dizimista.setNome1(dados.get("nome1"));
      dizimista.setLogradouro(dados.get("logradouro"));
      dizimista.setBairro(dados.get("bairro"));
      dizimista.setCep(Integer.parseInt(dados.get("cep")));
  }

  private Map<String, String> getDadosFormulario(String form){
      Map<String, String> dados = new HashMap<String, String>();
      dados.put("nome1", JSFHelper.getRequestParameter(form +
          UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(JSFHelper.getFacesContext()) + "nome1"));
      dados.put("logradouro", JSFHelper.getRequestParameter(form +
          UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(JSFHelper.getFacesContext()) + "logradouro"));
      dados.put("bairro", JSFHelper.getRequestParameter(form +
          UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(JSFHelper.getFacesContext()) + "bairro"));
      dados.put("cep", JSFHelper.getRequestParameter(form +
          UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(JSFHelper.getFacesContext()) + "cep"));
      dados.put("cidade", JSFHelper.getRequestParameter(form +
          UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(JSFHelper.getFacesContext()) + "cidade"));
      return dados;
  }
  ```

Comment: You shouldn't use an [actionListener to do an action method's job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener). You also shouldn't silent your exceptions. Does anything print on the console when validation fails?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and this link. I honestly still didn't know the difference between action and actionlistener. As regards the exception, I'm sorry, but just wanted to simplify the code. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: you're welcome. did you solved your problem, then?

Comment: Even with your suggestion regarding the action did not work, if you can help me, thank you. I changed to action but clicking the validation messages are displayed in h:messages, but the popupPanel appears without any text. I wanted the same were only displayed in case of success. And as is, even entering the fields correctly the insert method is not called.

Comment: can you post the full code of your MB code as it is now?

Comment: Yeah, I just saw it, but I've already posted an answer, check it out. Anyway, why don't you create fields in your MB to bind the values for `nome`, `logradouro`, etc, like you would for a normal JSF app? [see the Hello World here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: Regarding your last comment, my MB uses a normal bean (Dizimista.class injected by Spring), and this has the attributes listed. I'll check your response and return later. Thank you once again.

Comment: Then you could do `<h:inputText value="#{dizimistaMB.dizimista.nome}" />`, no?

Comment: Perfect! It Worked! I was using javascript (oncomplete) after receiving as suggested in another forum, but was not able to move forward from this point. With your help I will be able to continue. Very very thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. bom trampo aí! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render the contents of a `rich:popupPanel` through AJAX (rendering from `a4j:commandButton`), it may be best choose to display it conditionally using [its `show` attribute](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Panels.html#sect-Component_Reference-richpopupPanel-Showing_and_hiding_the_pop-up), instead of calling Javascript code (oncomplete).

So, I suggest you just add a condition for showing the `popupPanel`. Assuming that `textoModal` is null upon initialization, and your bean is a request scoped, you can just use something like this:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="pnlOk" modal="true"
       show="#{dizimistaMB.textoModal != null}" ...>
```

<sub>You may want to create a method in the backing bean something like `public boolean isShowTextoModal()` that may implement better rules than simply checking if a field is not null.</sub>

Then, you can change your button to this:

```
<h:commandButton id="btnInserirDizimista" value="Inserir"
       render="pnlMessages outPnlOk"
       action="#{dizimistaMB.inserirDizimista}" />
```

... and remove the `ActionEvent` argument from your method `inserirDizimista`, making it an [action method instead of a actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener).

This should get things going for you.